# Take a list of char's and replace any letters in a string not in the list

Tags: c#, regex

Supposed I have a list of chars:

```
List<char> letters = new List<char>();
```

Containing: 'f', 'e', 'j', 't', 'l'

I have a string:

```
string compareWord = "hello";
```

What would be the correct way to loop through the list `letters` and replace any missing letters from the char with a `_`.

For the example above once the string has been checked against the list `letters` we'd get
**output:**

```
_ e l l _
```

Comment: `[^fejtl]` matches any char but the specified chars.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's hard to help you without seeing what's wrong with your code

Comment: Vote to reopen as this can be done without Regex. `var chars = new HashSet(new[]{'f', 'e', 'j', 't', 'l'});    var result = new string(compareWord.Select(c => chars.Contains(c) ? c : '_').ToArray());`    There are longer but more efficient implementations using `StringBuilder` also